# Как преобразовать вложенный foreach с использованием Stream API?

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Как можно преобразовать следующий код с вложенным циклом foreach с использованием Stream API?

```
    private static final int calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBox() {
    int maximum = 0;
    int currentGranateSeeds = 0;
    int currentBoxSeeds = 0;
    
    for (Box box : boxesWithPomegrantes) {
        for (Pomegranate pomegranate : box) {
            currentGranateSeeds = pomegranate.getSeeds().size();
        }
        currentBoxSeeds += currentGranateSeeds;
        if (currentBoxSeeds > maximum) {
            maximum = currentBoxSeeds;
        }
    }
                                   
    return maximum;
}

private static List<String> findNamesOfBoxesWithMaximumSeeds() {
    List<String> namesOfBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    int maximum = calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBox();
    int currentGranateSeeds = 0;
    int currentBoxSeeds = 0;
    
    for (Box box : boxesWithPomegrantes) {
        for (Pomegranate pomegranate : box) {
            currentGranateSeeds = pomegranate.getSeeds().size();
        }
        currentBoxSeeds += currentGranateSeeds;
        if (currentBoxSeeds == maximum) {
            namesOfBoxes.add(box.getName());
        }
    }
    
    return namesOfBoxes;

}
```

Comment: Недостаточно информации. Добавьте недостяющий код (чтобы его хотя бы запустить можно было), а также дополнительную информацию что именно вы хотите сделать (для этого нажмите на кнопку "Править").

Comment: а IDE вам не подсказывает, что вложенный цикл выполняется впустую? Ведь фактически используется только последняя его итерация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое решение получилось у меня, и оно работает правильно:

```
private static final int calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBoxStream() {
         Optional<Box> res = boxesWithPomegrantes.stream()
          .collect(
              Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Box::getQuantytyOfSeedsInCurrentBox)));
         return res.get().getQuantytyOfSeedsInCurrentBox();
    }

    
    private static List<String> findNamesOfBoxesWithMaximumSeedsStream() {
        int maximum = calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBox();
        Map<Boolean, List<Box>> map = boxesWithPomegrantes.stream()
                                                          .collect(
                                                                  Collectors.partitioningBy(
                                                                          s -> s.getQuantytyOfSeedsInCurrentBox() == maximum));
        List<String> namesOfBoxes = map.entrySet().stream()
                             .filter(m -> m.getKey().booleanValue() == true)
                             .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                             .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                             .map(b -> b.getName())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return namesOfBoxes;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Для *корректного* поиска максимума гранатовых зернышек в одной коробке первый метод следует переписать следующим образом, с учётом того, что существует следующие иерархия классов:

- `Box` является коллекцией `Pomegranate` (например `Box extends ArrayList<Pomegranate>`), и имеет поле `name` с соответствующим геттером `getName`
- `Pomegranate` содержит коллекцию `Seed`

Тогда максимум можно найти следующим образом:

```java
private static final int calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBox(Collection<Box> boxesWithPomegranates) {
    return boxesWithPomegranates.stream() // Stream<Box>
            .mapToInt(b -> b.stream()     // Stream<Pomegranate> 
                .mapToInt(g -> g.getSeeds().size()) // IntStream seeds size
                .sum()
            )
            .max() // OptionalInt
            .orElse(-1); // для пустого ввода
}
```

Соответственно, для определения названий коробок, содержащих максимум зёрнышек, нужно применить `Stream::filter`:

```java
private static List<String> findNamesOfBoxesWithMaximumSeeds(Collection<Box> boxesWithPomegranates) {
    int max = calculateMaximumSeedsInOneBox(boxesWithPomegranates);

    return boxesWithPomegranates.stream()  // Stream<Box>
            .filter(b -> max == b.stream()
                .mapToInt(g -> g.getSeeds().size())
                .sum()
            )
            .map(Box::getName)  // Stream<String> названия коробок
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Альтернативный способ для получения списка названий коробок за один проход: сразу построить отсортированную мапу с ключом количеством зёрнышек и значением -- списком названий, и взять последний элемент такой мапы.

Также можно упростить код за счёт вынесения подсчёта количеств зёрнышек в класс `Box`:

```java
// class Box
public int totalSeedCount() {
    return this.stream().mapToInt(g -> g.getSeeds().size()).sum();
}
```

```java
private static List<String> namesOfBoxesWithMaxSeeds(Collection<Box> boxesWithPomegranates) {
    return boxesWithPomegranates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Box::totalSeedCount, // ключ - сумма зёрнышек в коробке
                TreeMap::new, // отсортированная мапа по возрастанию
                Collectors.mapping(Box::getName, Collectors.toList())
            ))
            .lastEntry() // Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> макс.ключ
            .getValue(); // List<String>
}
```